# Displaying custom field data on a page with a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array, custom-fields

I have got a selection of custom fields set up for use on a page of a website, and I have no problem in echo'ing the values out onto the page using get_post_meta.

To save multiple callbacks to the db, by implementing multiple variations of the get_post_meta, I decided to use get_post_meta($post->ID) and then pull the various custom fields that exist in the arrays within that.

The question lie's with displaying this data, I have included the code that I am using for this proccess below, however rather than using multiple if statements to display the custom field values, I was wondering if anyone could point me towards a more simplistic direction of coding this.

This solution works perfectly, with regards to displaying the data, but I am wondering how some of you ninja's may do it more cleverly, and maybe save some lines of code!!

It would be nice to hear your solutions to this problem(even though it's a pretty straight froward one I'm sure), to enhance my understanding of the language!!

```
<?php $custom = get_post_meta($post->ID);   
    if($custom['wpcf-description'][0]==!null){
      echo "</br>";
      echo "<p>";
      echo $custom['wpcf-description'][0];
      echo "</p>"; }

    if($custom['wpcf-length-overall'][0]==!null){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>Overall Length: </td>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo $custom['wpcf-length-overall'][0];
      echo " Meters";
      echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>"; } ?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving *working* code, belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks brasfilo, I will repost it there

Comment: Try asking for migration first using a custom flag.

Comment: See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667)

Comment: Thanks brasfilo, I have flagged it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you don't want to echo result when you have empty string etc., you can use empty() to check this.

`<br>` must not be used to divide content, it's a bad practice. Best way is to implement css class/id and manage your layout that way.

Also you can implement temporary variables for data to tidy code a little bit, 2 more lines, but more readable.

```
<?php 
        $custom = get_post_meta($post->ID);
        $desc = $custom['wpcf-description'][0];
        $total = $custom['wpcf-length-overall'][0];

        if(!empty($desc))
            echo "<p class='newline'>".$desc."</p>";

        if(!empty($total))
            echo "<tr><td>Overall Length: </td><td>".$total." Meters</td></tr>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback rm-rf, this is a good insight for me as I'm new to php.